# Oracle SQL query performance

Tags: oracle

I have 3 tables trader, city_state, city_present.

I have 4million rows in trader table and my query is taking atleast 20sec.  Few records in city_present and cities table.

Below is my query.

select t.trader_id, t.name, t.city, t.state from 
     (
     SELECT distinct c.city, c.state
     FROM city_present p,city_state c
     WHERE p.name = 'TEST_TEST'  
     AND c.city = p.city  
     AND c.state = p.state  
     ) 
    cs, trader t
    where 
    AND t.city = cs.city
    AND t.state = cs.state
    AND t.name = 'john test'
    AND t.is_valid= 1

I have index on customer (city, state, name, valid_customer)
Subquery is taking less than a second .. it is outer query that is taking around 20sec.

Can someone please help me how to reduce the query time.

Comment: For starters, showing the explain plan would help.

Comment: How many rows are returned by your query?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an index on trader.name, possibly including trader.is_valid as well?

And is the distinct really required? Does that really need to be an in-line view, or could it be a regular join?

Comment: about 35 rows are returned.

Comment: do I need index on trader name, is_valid, city, state columns or just name and is_valid columns?

Comment: You almost certainly need an index on trader.name as a minimum. Whether you need one on is_valid depends on how much time it would save to be able to find just the is_valid=1 from the index without going to the table. How many rows do you have for each value of is_valid? You probably don't need all the trader columns in the index -- try it without first.

Comment: almost all rows have is_valid=1

Comment: I'd just index trader.name then.

Comment: thank you David.  my query is retuning multiple rows with same values of t.trader_id, t.name, t.city, t.state .. when I use DISTINCT it is becoming slow .. is there any other alternative for this

Comment: Rewrite the query without the inline view, using regular joins. Apply the distinct to the new query. Post the new query in the question, and post the execution plans with and without distinct if there is still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you can try without adding anything to your schema: in your subquery you never select anything from city_present, so you can turn it into `IN` / `EXISTS`

```
 select t.trader_id, t.name, t.city, t.state from 
 (
 SELECT c.city, c.state
 FROM city_state c
 WHERE EXISTS (
     select null
     from city_present p
     where
     p.name = 'TEST_TEST'  
     AND c.city = p.city  
     AND c.state = p.state)
 ) 
cs, trader t
where 
AND t.city = cs.city
AND t.state = cs.state
AND t.name = 'john test'
AND t.is_valid= 1
```

Then, the same thing applies to cs. So you could rewrite to:

```
select t.trader_id, t.name, t.city, t.state from 
trader t
where 
exists (
    SELECT null
    FROM city_state c
    WHERE EXISTS (
         select null
         from city_present p
         where
         p.name = 'TEST_TEST'  
         AND c.city = p.city  
         AND c.state = p.state)
    AND t.city = c.city
    AND t.state = c.state
) 
AND t.name = 'john test'
AND t.is_valid= 1
```

You can also try flattening the subqueries:

```
select t.trader_id, t.name, t.city, t.state from 
trader t
where 
exists (
     SELECT null
     FROM city_present p,city_state c
     WHERE p.name = 'TEST_TEST'  
     AND c.city = p.city  
     AND c.state = p.state  
     AND t.city = c.city
     AND t.state = c.state
) 
AND t.name = 'john test'
AND t.is_valid= 1
```

From here, you should investigate about indexing:

- trader.name and / or trader.id
- (city_state.city, city_state.state) and (city_present.city, city_present.state)